# SQL Parameters - Where to Use

Tags: mysql, sql, database, parameters

I'm in the midst of applying SQL parameters to my project to prevent SQL Injection.

Do I add parameters to every query in my application, including the queries that don't have any user interaction?

For example, if my user wanted to search for a keyword and submitted a text field. I've added the parameterized method to the query that used that keyword, to stop the user adding something malicious. But underneath this query, is another query, which get's the keyword ID from the top search and runs it's own little query elsewhere.

This is what's confusing to me,  do I add the parameter method to this query too, even though the keyword ID wasn't from the user?

Many thanks

Comment: Please use placeholders consistently (read: everywhere). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use parameterized queries in any place you have parameters.

The fact that *today* no user input is used on a specific query doesn't mean tomorrow will be the same. Code changes. Perhaps a malicious user will figure out how to compromise the first query and then the second one.

You should think about [defense in depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_%28computing%29).

Comment: +1 "use parameterized queries in any place you have parameters". Could not be simpler

Comment: Here's Jeff Atwood on the subject: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should be a parameter too. Otherwise, you have to keep track of what values that you have inserted into the db came from a user - there's nothing to prevent the name of "'; DROP DATABASE". If you're blindly trusting data from the database to be sanitized, you're bound to get it wrong at some point.

Something like:

```
SELECT Rows FROM TABLE2 WHERE KeywordId = (
   SELECT KeywordId FROM TABLE1 WHERE UserInput = @u
)
```

would be ok, because your SQL engine will use parameters internally. It's the logic like:

```
var keywordId = sql_exec("SELECT KeywordId FROM Table1 WHERE UserInput = @u", userInput);
var rows = sql_exec("SELECT Rows FROM Table2 WHERE KeywordId = '" + keywordId + "'");
```

that would be incorrect - since the application is not using parameters for external and variable input.